# Exception building gradle task launchIosDevice

Tags: ios, gradle, javafx, task, gluon-mobile

After I updated Ios at new version (I think before this thing it was ok), I have this exception when I try to launch Gradle task "launchIosDevice":

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.robovm.libimobiledevice.Callbacks.callInstproxyCallback(Callbacks.java:66)
```

Can anyone help me to understand the problem?
Thank you in advance.

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.2'

    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/'
    }
    maven { 
       url('https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/')
    }
}

mainClassName = 'it.wstech.lex.LXMainApplication'

dependencies { 
    compile 'com.airhacks:afterburner.mfx:1.6.2'
    compile fileTree(dir: '***', include: ['*.jar'])  
    compile fileTree(dir: '***', include: ['*.jar'])   
    compile fileTree(dir: '***', include: ['*.jar'])  
    compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: ['*.jar'])  

    androidCompile 'org.glassfish:javax.json:1.0.4' 
    compile "com.gluonhq:charm:4.3.0"


}


jfxmobile {


    javafxportsVersion = '8.60.8'

    downConfig {
        version "3.3.0-SNAPSHOT"
        plugins 'display','browser','cache', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage', 'local-notifications', 'device','connectivity','dialer','orientation','runtime-args', 'push-notifications' 
    }
    android {
      manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'          
      compileSdkVersion = 21
         signingConfig {
            storeFile file('***')
            storePassword 'wstechsrl'
            keyAlias '***'
            keyPassword '***'
        }

         dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    }


    ios {

    iosSignIdentity = '****'
    iosProvisioningProfile = '****' 
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
                       arch = 'arm64'
                        ipaArchs=['arm64']


        forceLinkClasses = [
                'com.gluonhq.**.*',
                'it.wstech.**.*',              
                'javax.annotations.**.*',
                'javax.inject.**.*',
                'javax.json.**.*',
                'org.glassfish.json.**.*'
        ]


    }
}

[ 96%] Uploading /Volumes/RoboVM RAM Disk/tmp/Users/wstechsrl/Desktop/workspace_fx/strikenball/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/strikenball.app/lib/robovm-cocoatouch-2.3.0.jar...
[ 97%] Uploading /Volumes/RoboVM RAM Disk/tmp/Users/wstechsrl/Desktop/workspace_fx/strikenball/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/strikenball.app/lib/robovm-objc-2.3.0.jar...
[ 98%] Uploading /Volumes/RoboVM RAM Disk/tmp/Users/wstechsrl/Desktop/workspace_fx/strikenball/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/strikenball.app/strikenball...
[100%] Upload complete
[  0%] Beginning installation...
[  5%] CreatingStagingDirectory
[ 15%] ExtractingPackage
[ 20%] InspectingPackage
[ 20%] TakingInstallLock
[ 30%] PreflightingApplication
[ 30%] InstallingEmbeddedProfile
[ 40%] VerifyingApplication
[ 50%] CreatingContainer
[ 60%] InstallingApplication
[ 70%] PostflightingApplication
[ 80%] SandboxingApplication
[ 90%] GeneratingApplicationMap
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.robovm.libimobiledevice.Callbacks.callInstproxyCallback(Callbacks.java:66)
```

Comment: Are you using the jfxmobile plugin? Can you post your build.gradle? Run `./gradlew --info launchIosDevice` and post a more detailed stacktrace? Also, does `./gradew createIpa` work for you?

Comment: Yes, I'm using jfxmobileplugin, I posted the last lines of stacktrace and the build.gradle. The createIpa task work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After updating my iPad to iOS 10.3 I can reproduce the error running `./gradlew --info launchIOSDevice`:

```
[100%] Upload complete
[  0%] Beginning installation...
[  5%] CreatingStagingDirectory
[ 15%] ExtractingPackage
[ 20%] InspectingPackage
[ 20%] TakingInstallLock
[ 30%] PreflightingApplication
[ 30%] InstallingEmbeddedProfile
[ 40%] VerifyingApplication
[ 50%] CreatingContainer
[ 60%] InstallingApplication
[ 70%] PostflightingApplication
[ 80%] SandboxingApplication
[ 90%] GeneratingApplicationMap
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.robovm.libimobiledevice.Callbacks.callInstproxyCallback(Callbacks.java:66)
```

There is something broken with the new iOS version, and this is something that needs to be fixed by Mobidevelop, the Robovm fork. Once they've solved it, it will require a new version of the jfxmobile plugin.

There is already an [issue](https://github.com/MobiDevelop/robovm/issues/123) created, but maybe you can also post yours.

In the meantime, the workaround is installing the app manually once you have built the ipa:

Run `./gradlew createIpa`, locate the ipa under /build/javafxports/ios, double click on it and it will opened with iTunes. Then it will be downloaded and installed on your iOS device.